# AJUDA C# VARIÁVEL

Tags: c#

Boa tarde, alguem pode me ajudar em um codigo?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Launcher.WesT
{    
    class Globals
    {

        private Config Configs_ = null;
        public string URLL()
        {
            Configs_ = Config.GetConfigs();
            Configs_.LoadLocalConfig("config.wz", "21456");
            string SITE = Configs_.LINKUP;

            return (SITE);
        }

        public static string ServerURL = URLL();
```

como eu faço para essa linha
public static string ServerURL = URLL();

ler o URLL()?

desde ja obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método `URLL()` não é `static`.

Uma alternativa é deixá-lo `static`.

Ou mantenha como está e deixe a variável sem valor, e em determinado método não-static você atribui usando `ServerURL = this.URLL();`

---

Se souber inglês, esse site pode ser útil:

[C# - Static](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-static)

Comment: coloquei a resposta assim, nao sei usar esse site ainda kkkkk, obrigado msm

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), tenho certeza de que vai adorar o StackOverflow quando aprender tudo que ele têm a oferecer. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Config Configs_ = null;  //<-- STATIC q nao tinha

        public static string URLL()
        {
            Configs_ = Config.GetConfigs();
            Configs_.LoadLocalConfig("config.wz", "21456");
            string SITE = Configs_.LINKUP;

            return (SITE);
        }

        public static string ServerURL = URLL();
```

Fiz assim e parece q deu certo, tive q colocar static na `public static Config Configs_ = null;`tbm

desde ja obrigado, se alguem tever tbm alguma outra solução q pode ajudar agradeço..